Odd rysnc hard link handling over ssh
I have a filesystem, /mnt/tosh, that I want to transfer periodically to a backup over ssh using rsync.
It contains a subdir /mnt/tosh/vorbis that itself contains dirs that contain hard links, eg
glower /mnt/tosh/vorbis/yayas> ls -l
total 111872
-rw-rw-r-- 2 jg jg  9708988 Sep 30  2023 yayas001.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 2 jg jg  9081135 Sep 30  2023 yayas002.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 2 jg jg  9071545 Sep 30  2023 yayas003.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 2 jg jg 11862262 Sep 30  2023 yayas004.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 2 jg jg 21782906 Sep 30  2023 yayas005.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 2 jg jg 16468352 Sep 30  2023 yayas006.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 2 jg jg  7306102 Sep 30  2023 yayas007.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 2 jg jg 10929144 Sep 30  2023 yayas008.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 2 jg jg  8580986 Sep 30  2023 yayas009.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 2 jg jg  9743549 Sep 30  2023 yayas010.mp3
glower /mnt/tosh/vorbis/yayas>

.. but after doing this:
$ rsync -avH --delete -e ssh /mnt/tosh minako:/drobojoin

I'm finding spurious repeated hard link dotfiles on the target after it completes:
minako /drobojoin/tosh/vorbis/yayas> ls -la
total 224096
drwxrwxr-x   2 jg jg     4096 Jul 16 14:29 .
drwxrwxr-x 194 jg jg     4096 Aug 23 11:09 ..
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  9708988 Sep 30  2023 yayas001.mp3
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  9708988 Sep 30  2023 .yayas001.mp3.3008
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  9081135 Sep 30  2023 yayas002.mp3
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  9081135 Sep 30  2023 .yayas002.mp3.3008
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  9071545 Sep 30  2023 yayas003.mp3
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  9071545 Sep 30  2023 .yayas003.mp3.3008
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg 11862262 Sep 30  2023 yayas004.mp3
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg 11862262 Sep 30  2023 .yayas004.mp3.3008
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg 21782906 Sep 30  2023 yayas005.mp3
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg 21782906 Sep 30  2023 .yayas005.mp3.3008
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg 16468352 Sep 30  2023 yayas006.mp3
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg 16468352 Sep 30  2023 .yayas006.mp3.3008
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  7306102 Sep 30  2023 yayas007.mp3
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  7306102 Sep 30  2023 .yayas007.mp3.3008
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg 10929144 Sep 30  2023 yayas008.mp3
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg 10929144 Sep 30  2023 .yayas008.mp3.3008
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  8580986 Sep 30  2023 yayas009.mp3
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  8580986 Sep 30  2023 .yayas009.mp3.3008
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  9743549 Sep 30  2023 yayas010.mp3
-rw-rw-r--   3 jg jg  9743549 Sep 30  2023 .yayas010.mp3.3008
minako /drobojoin/tosh/vorbis/yayas> 

If I just transfer the vorbis dir in isolation, ie:
$ rsync -avH --delete -e ssh /mnt/tosh/vorbis minako:/drobojoin/tosh

I don't get the spurious files. So it seems to be related to the scale or complexity of the transfer.
Anyone seen similar? There's an easy workaround of course (ie to exclude vorbis from a first pass and transfer separately later) but perhaps there a neater way? Although I'm thinking it must be a bug.

Wow. Tricky. Can you create a strace from the rsync receiver on the minako? I have never seen any similar, but rsync is working by first uploading a temporary file, and then renaming it atomically to the original target. Somehow it can be turned off, but probably you do not want to see half-uploaded files in the case of a breakup on any reason. I think, the first part had happened and then something made rsync unable to get the job done. I wish you a real answer by someone who has seen it already and found a solution.

Thanks for the reply. If your hypothesis is right, then whatever prevents rsync finishing off happens every time - it's very repeatable.

Otherways, -H makes rsync to handle the case if there are hard links on the source side. Then they will be hard links also on the target side. For example, if yayas008.mp3 and yayas005.mp3 would be hard links, they would become hard links also on the target site. However, exactly that is what very rarely happens in a directory of mp3 music. I think the purpose of your -H is to accelerate the backup, i.e. you do not want to copy again the not changed content. I backup my family photos on the same way. I use only rsync -vr --size-only, that see only file existence and size.

Note, if the remote side is some exotical filesystem, like a davfs, or some NAS network share, maybe no hard links are supported on it. That would explain everything. Or, the remote part of the rsync is believing, it has the permission to overwrite the files, but in the reality it has not (might be any permission trouble). Here are the rsync flags you likely want to know.

Thanks for the replies. The remote filesystem is mergerfs which in this case is a lightweight overlay for ext4. It does support hard links nicely - again, there's no trouble at all when I rsync just the 'vorbis' directory over, which is largely composed of hard links within subdirs. I'm using -H so they're copied over as hard links rather than duplicate files which would chew up too much space on the target, as well as making a restore painful to recover from.
